# Why doesn't coil in an Ac generator not get deflected in accordance to the flemming's left hand rule when current starts to flow through it

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-current

Why doesn't coil in an Ac generator not get deflected in accordance to the `Flemming's  left hand rule` when current starts to flow through it.

When the coil is rotated by some mechanical means, electric current is induced in the coil, and current starts to flow through it. Now if we apply `Flemming's left hand rule` the direction of coil rotation is different than what is obtained when `Right hand rule` is used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a generator work a force/torque is applied to the coil and a voltage is induced.
If the coil is part of a complete electrical circuit the induced voltage results in an induced current in the circuit.
The direction of the voltage/current can be deduced by using Fleming's right had rule.

You are quite right that the current carrying coil in a magnetic field experiences a force/torque whose direction can be deduced using Fleming's left hand rule, and that force/torque is in the opposite direction to the force/torque applied to rotate the coil.
Here you have Lenz's law in action with the induced current in such a direction FRHR) as to oppose (FLHR) the motion producing it.

Comment: So this means that if we are rotating the coil, it is opposed by a force that is smaller in magnitude to the force applied to rotate the coil, which still allows it to rotate but slower than what it would have achieved if the opposing force wasn't applied.  But if this happens, every time the rotating speed significantly decreases the induced current also decreases, which means that gradually the induction of current stops. Because the coil started to rotate slower and slower.

Comment: The applied force/torque does work and that work becomes "electrical" energy.  If there was no opposition to the applied force/work from the induced current then once the coil was rotating no applied force/torque would be needed to keep the coil rotating and yet an induced current was being produced.

Comment: I understood. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[Fleming's rules at www.electricaltechnology.org](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2020/12/flemings-left-right-hand-rule.html) show and tell the difference between the two.  The left-hand rule is for motors: the current causes the wire to move.  The right-hand rule is for generators: the motion of the wire causes the current.  These rules are a quick way to relate motion, current, and field directions.  They are not the basis of electric force on a wire (motor) and magnetic induction (generator).